# cumulative column dataframe

Tags: python, cumulative-sum

[image]

df['Volume cummulated'] = df['Positive_Negative_Volume'].cumsum()

I can't get a correct cummulative sum on the right column

[image]

Comment: You haven't split the first column yet. your `df['Positive_Negative_Volume'][0]` is `5643397.6053299 561` this. I think pandas might interpret that as a string or an object. If you want it as a float, you should either split or remove the gap.

Comment: yes I have two columns not one, but maybe the cumsum do not understand well the format of 5643397.6053299

Comment: I do not think that is case. I have used it before and have faced no noticeable problems.

Comment: this is very weird as you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that this helps solve your problem, but have a look at this-

```py
import pandas as pd

values = [5643397.6053299,
          3496291.56664438,
          -5480337.35603218,
          12944037.55061038,
          6574092.80269061,
          -5331202.45221019,
          -4508747.90607631,
          5609366.20613776,
          4719385.57010436,
          -4840785.79801116,
          4149434.68258942,
          -6587934.91085111,
          12442827.1189019]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'values': values})
print(df['values'].cumsum().values)
```

output

```
[ 5643397.6053299   9139689.17197428  3659351.8159421  16603389.36655248
 23177482.16924309 17846279.7170329  13337531.81095659 18946898.01709435
 23666283.58719871 18825497.78918755 22974932.47177697 16386997.56092586
 28829824.67982776]
```

I would suggest you to run `df.dtypes` and `df.describe()`, it could help pin-point the problem